# after clicking a href attribute to redirect it show strange rectangle

Tags: html, css

i decided to make redirects with images but i have small problem.

Look at this screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEnNB.png

This is this item:

`<p><div><a title="Home" href="/home"><img src="/icons/home.svg" width="55" height="55" /></a></div></p>`

It shows strange rectangle, i dont want to show it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<div>` cannot be inside a paragraph element.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't redirect? (I'm not clear what the 'after' means).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That outline is an accessibility feature (Which might be added as part of a CSS theme, but hard to know without the full context of the codebase). However, removing it is not a good idea, as it will worsen the experience for people with visibility impairment (Check http://www.outlinenone.com/).

What we can do, however, is make it look better. You have a `<div>` with a `<a>` nested in a `<p>`, it being the reason for the rectangle not encasing the whole icon and instead overlapping on top of it, as it believes it to be an inline element ([Ideally, you don't want to use block elements in `p` tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html)). Here, you're getting block elements, such as a `<div>` and an `<img>` inside of the `<p>`). So what I recommend is:

1. Remove `<p>` and `<div>`, and leave it only wrapped in the `<a>`
2. Add the `display: inline-block` CSS property to the `<a>` tag, resulting in:

```
    <a style="display:inline-block;" title="Home" href="/home">
      <img src="/icons/home.svg" width="55" height="55" />
    </a>
```

If you want a block element, simply remove the `<p>` tag:

```
    <div>
        <a title="Home" href="/home">
          <img src="/icons/home.svg" width="55" height="55" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without full context it will be difficult to answer but:

1. Try to set a element `display:block` or `display:inline-block`
2. Try to set IMG width and height as `style="width:55px;height:55px"`

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block` to the `<a>` tag

```html
<p>
<div>
<a style="display:inline-block" title="Home" href="/home">
<img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1357549139/photo/shot-of-an-adorable-baby-boy-wearing-a-hoody-towel.webp?s=612x612&w=is&k=20&c=MvuPLKqQhs7f6ZIsPf8oTgw08OiCvmmjJNeNdL0FG4M=" width="55" height="55" />
</a>
</div>
</p>
```